# lwc lightning-input checkbox not getting unchecked

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have a scenario where i have a list of records which has checkbox field like below. Here i am selecting one record at a time , means i cant select 2 or more records at a time which is working fine.

the issue is i am now unable to unselect the checkbox. Below is the code which i am using to have one checkbox checked at a time. I need to uncheck the checked checkbox.

[image]

```
getaccrowid(e) {
    console.log(e)
    const boxes = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input');
    boxes.forEach(box =>
        box.checked = e.target.name === box.name
    );
    this.dupaccid = this.accdata[e.target.value].Id
}
```

HTML

```
 <lightning-input value={index} type="checkbox" name={row.Id}
                                                onchange={getaccrowid}>
                                            </lightning-input>
```

Comment: you need to provide more code, html, js aspecially the onclick handler

Comment: Done.. added more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in your `onchange` handler, you always check the one clicked checkbox no matter what the current state of the checkbox is. You need to create `if` and branch the logic as follows.

```
getaccrowid(e) {
    console.log(e)
    if (e.target.checked) {
        const boxes = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input');
        boxes.forEach(box =>
            box.checked = e.target.name === box.name
        );
        this.dupaccid = this.accdata[e.target.value].Id
    }
}
```